# Wireless disconnects when power management enabled on RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

Tags: wireless, ralink

My wireless disconnects(randomly, but I'm sure it's when power saving kicks in) whenever power management is enabled. The only thing that keeps it from happening is to keeping the wifi power management = off, adding the file: “/etc/pm/power.d/wireless”

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iwconfig wlan1 power off
```

Is there a right way or correct way of taking care of this problem without disabling power management?

Comment: try this: http://www.techytalk.info/ralink-rt3090-ubuntu-driver-ppa/ (I not trying it jet, but, it seems that this link provide driver with correctly work with power management)

Comment: There is nothing in that PPA for 11.10. I already tried it. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it is the way all the wireless experts have people do it. I have had many people do it and it has not caused any issues except it might use a little more battery power. I myself use this method.